# Selecting second line every 3 lines from web scraped variable with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping

i webscraped this

```
['',
 'Aldoar, Foz Do Douro E Nevogilde',
 'Ontem 16:36',
 '',
 'Mafamude E Vilar Do Paraíso',
 '3',
 '',
 'Estela',
 '1',
 '',
 'Oeiras E São Julião Da Barra, Paço De Arcos E Caxias',
 '30',
 '',
 'Olivais',
 '29',
 '',
 'Olivais',
 '29',
 '',
 'Olivais',
 '29',
 '',
 'Nogueira, Fraião E Lamaçães',
 '28',
 '',
 'Fernão Ferro',
 '21',
 '',
 'Ovar, São João, Arada E São Vicente De Pereira Jusã',
 '21',
 '',
 'Eiras E São Paulo De Frades',
 '20',
 '',
 'Montijo E Afonsoeiro',
 '20',
 '',
 'Alcabideche',
 '19',
 '',
 'Bougado (São Martinho E Santiago)',
 '14',
 '',
 'Campo E Sobrado',
 '14',
 '',
 'Vila do Conde',
 '8']
```

and want to select the 2nd line from every 3 lines using python/pandas,so that i end up with:

Aldoar, Foz Do Douro E Nevogilde

Mafamude E Vilar Do Paraíso

Estela

and so on

thx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```python
s = ['',
 'Aldoar, Foz Do Douro E Nevogilde',
 'Ontem 16:36',
 '',
 'Mafamude E Vilar Do Paraíso',
 '3',
 '',
 'Estela',
 '1',
 '',
 'Oeiras E São Julião Da Barra, Paço De Arcos E Caxias',
 '30',
 '',
 'Olivais',
 '29',
 '',
 'Olivais',
 '29',
 '',
 'Olivais',
 '29',
 '',
 'Nogueira, Fraião E Lamaçães',
 '28',
 '',
 'Fernão Ferro',
 '21',
 '',
 'Ovar, São João, Arada E São Vicente De Pereira Jusã',
 '21',
 '',
 'Eiras E São Paulo De Frades',
 '20',
 '',
 'Montijo E Afonsoeiro',
 '20',
 '',
 'Alcabideche',
 '19',
 '',
 'Bougado (São Martinho E Santiago)',
 '14',
 '',
 'Campo E Sobrado',
 '14',
 '',
 'Vila do Conde',
 '8']
```

```
>>> s[1::3]
['Aldoar, Foz Do Douro E Nevogilde',
 'Mafamude E Vilar Do Paraíso',
 'Estela',
 'Oeiras E São Julião Da Barra, Paço De Arcos E Caxias',
 'Olivais',
 'Olivais',
 'Olivais',
 'Nogueira, Fraião E Lamaçães',
 'Fernão Ferro',
 'Ovar, São João, Arada E São Vicente De Pereira Jusã',
 'Eiras E São Paulo De Frades',
 'Montijo E Afonsoeiro',
 'Alcabideche',
 'Bougado (São Martinho E Santiago)',
 'Campo E Sobrado',
 'Vila do Conde']
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to select one element every *three* elements starting from the *second one* i.e. `index=1`.

You can achieve this with the built-in list `__getitem__`:

```
X[1::3]
```

Where `X` is your initial list.

Answer (score 0):

This will work :

```
ls=['',
 'Aldoar, Foz Do Douro E Nevogilde',
 'Ontem 16:36',
 '',
 'Mafamude E Vilar Do Paraíso',
 '3',
 '',
 'Estela',
 ...
 '14',
 '',
 'Vila do Conde',
 '8']
```

Now you can use this method which is faster than the built in method

```
def chunkIt(seq, num):
    avg = len(seq) / float(num)
    out = []
    last = 0.0

    while last < len(seq):
        out.append(seq[int(last):int(last + avg)])
        last += avg

    return out

h=len(ls)/3
chunk=chunkIt(ls,h)
# using list comprehension
print('\n'.join([chunk[i][1] for i in range(len(chunk))]))
```

> Time taken: 0.03806419999999999

OR

```
>>> print(ls[1::3])
```

> Time Taken: 0.07802389999999992

Comment: You need to credit the original author of this function...